# Locating phone using phone number

Tags: android, location

I want to locate particular phone by using phone number. can any one guide me how should do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "locate phone"?

Comment: I mean I want to get current location of that particular cell phone

Comment: Particular phone? Which one? What brand? Andriod? iPhone? Please be more specific and provide some feedback on what you've already tried or want to do.

Comment: means which ever number i want to search eg. if i want to search location of this no: +34-689-55-44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How accurate does the location need to be? If you're trying to get something fairly approximate, check out the [android geolocation guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html).

Getting a location merely from a phone number is much more difficult/not useful. You can narrow down country by country code, then hopefully said country uses area codes to make it a little easier. Of course, nothing about any of this means the phone is **currently** even in said country/area code.

Comment: Yes i have gone through it but i want to locate another cell from my device then do u know how can i achieve it?

Comment: I'd forget about doing it by phone number. There's probably some legality issues there as well. A workable architecture might be to have the two phones run your application, and they communicate either directly or over a server to send each other their current locations, or enough information to determine them (from the guide above). This doesn't even involve any security or privacy considerations. It's an undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the prefix of the number. For example in Spain a number starts by +34. A complete phone number can be +34-689-55-44

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't simply "locate" a phone based on phone number, pretty much only the police has the resources to do so.

But if your application is running on both phones, you can probably make ends meet. You'll need to retreive the phone number of the phone you're trying to get the location from :

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

And if the phone is active and your application is running in the background (perhaps a service), you locate it with the built in GPS or Phone Network (less accurate) and send the coordinates back where you need them. Here's an example :

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

This won't be the simplest process ever as you'll probably want to store the last seen location of a device every time your application gets focus in order to be able to give an estimated location even if the phone is turned off or your application isn't running. So you'll have to set up a robust server/database architecture with security since the information you're going to be dealing with can be somewhat delicate.

You'll also need to add several permissions in the manifest.

Comment: It is for telephony service on your device i want to get location of another device